# for item in list, find same item in dictionary, find value of item and sum all items

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am new at stackoverflow and new with Python or any programming language for that matter. 
I have a relatively simple problem but I can't figure out how to get it working.

I need to find out the total bill of the items in a shopping list.
Shopping list data is in a list and price data is in dictionary.

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for food in food:
        if food in prices:
            total += prices[food]
            return total
```

I do not get back anything.

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards IWTLP

Answer (score 4):

You need to indent correctly the return statement. Return after all computation is done, not in the middle of the for loop.

```
def compute_bill(foods):
    total = 0
    for food in foods:
        if food in prices:
            total += prices[food]
    return total  # <---
```

And, don't forget to call the function:

```
print(compute_bill(shopping_list))
```

---

Another version that use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
def compute_bill(foods):
    return sum(prices.get(food, 0) for food in foods)
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Yoel, I renamed the iterator `food) to`foods` so that its name differs from that of the iterated object.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. And sorry for the edit. What about remain the OP's original code, e.g. no indent?

Comment: I would also suggest renaming the iterator (`food`) so that its name differs from that of the iterated object (`food` as well).

Comment: @Yoel, Thank you for the suggestion. I updated the code accordingly (`food` -> `foods`)

Answer (score 0):

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]
prices = { "banana": 4, "apple": 2, "orange": 1.5, "pear": 3 }

def compute_bill(shLst):
   return sum([price for food,price in prices.items() if food in shLst])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to sum all the value of all the items in the cart dictionnary
you can simply do

```
sum(prices.values())
```

if you want to filter the item in the cart from a list:

```
sum([value for key,value in prices.items() if key in shopping_list])
```

Comment: Perhaps `sum(prices.get(key, 0) for key in shopping_list)` is cleaner.

Comment: You don't need a list comprehension in this case, as a generator expression will do.

Comment: thanks using generator only saves a lot of time if you have a big list

Comment: Its not (just) to save time, its to make the code simpler. Unless a list is necessary, you should use generator expressions instead of list comprehensions.